# How to make java delay for a few seconds?

Tags: java, delay

Hey all I have this code. I want to delay my program for a few seconds and display "scanning..."

Here's what I have. This compiles but doesn't delay anything

```java
int i = 1;
if (i == 1) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("Scanning...");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is in a mouseEvent btw

Comment: That is 1 millisecond. Please read the apis/manuals when you have questions like these.

Comment: Wait but it still doesn't say scanning while it's delayed (sorry I'm a highschool student)

Comment: That's because you're printing *after* you call sleep.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Sorry I'm stupid. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Would it be possible to display "Scanning..." delay 1 seconds then display "Scanning..." again? in the same try catch

Comment: @user2918193 you can even have it hundreds of times. just repeat the `System.out.println("Scanning...");
 Thread.sleep(1000);` and change the printing

Answer (score 25):

If you want to pause then use `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
```

To sleep for one second or for 10 minutes

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(10);
```

Or Thread Sleep

```
try        
{
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} 
catch(InterruptedException ex) 
{
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

see also the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

`TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep()` will call `Thread.sleep`. The only difference is readability and using TimeUnit is probably easier to understand for non obvious durations.

but if you want to solve your issue

```
        int timeToWait = 10; //second
        System.out.print("Scanning")
        try {
            for (int i=0; i<timeToWait ; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.print(".")
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

`Thread.sleep()` takes in the number of milliseconds to sleep, not seconds.

Sleeping for one millisecond is not noticeable. Try `Thread.sleep(1000)` to sleep for one second.

Answer (score 4):

> This is in a mouseEvent btw

If this is in a Swing GUI, then get rid of all calls to `Thread.sleep(...)` as doing so can put the entire GUI to sleep rendering it useless. Instead use a Swing Timer to produce any delays in the GUI while letting it still update its graphics.

You'll also want to avoid `System.out.println(...)` calls, except when debugging, and instead display user notifications in the GUI itself, perhaps in a status JLabel or as a message dialog.

Answer (score 4):

**Java:**

For calculating times we use this method:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


    public static String getCurrentTime() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
}
```

Second:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

System.out.println("Start delay of 10 seconds, Time is: " + getCurrentTime());
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
System.out.println("And delay of 10 seconds, Time is: " + getCurrentTime());
```

Output:

> Start delay of 10 seconds, Time is: 14:19:08
>
> And delay of 10 seconds, Time is: 14:19:18

Minutes:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

System.out.println("Start delay of 1 Minute, Time is: " + getCurrentTime());
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
System.out.println("And delay of 1 Minute, Time is: " + getCurrentTime());
```

Output:

> Start delay of 1 Minute, Time is: 14:21:20
>
> And delay of 1 Minute, Time is: 14:22:20

Milliseconds:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

System.out.println("Start delay of 2000 milliseconds, Time is: " +getCurrentTime());
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("And delay of 2000 milliseconds, Time is: " + getCurrentTime());
```

Output:

> Start delay of 2000 milliseconds, Time is: 14:23:44
>
> And delay of 2000 milliseconds, Time is: 14:23:46

Or:

```
Thread.sleep(1000); //milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `System.out.println("Scanning...")` in a catch block. 
Do you want to put that in try?

Answer (score 2):

```
 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (getActivity() != null)
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> tvCovidAlert.startAnimation(animBounce));
                }
            }, DELAY_TIME_MILI_SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per java documentation definition of Thread.sleep is :

```
Thread.sleep(t);
where t => time in millisecons to sleep
```

If you want to sleep for 1 second you should have :

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems, you aren't delaying by much (`.sleep` is milliseconds, not seconds), and you're attempting to print in your `catch` statement. Your code should look more like:

```
if (i==1) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Scanning...");
        Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Thread.sleep(2000); //2000 for 2 seconds`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Thread.sleep()` method.

This is used to pause the execution of current thread for specified time in **milliseconds**. The argument value for milliseconds **can’t be negative**, else it throws **IllegalArgumentException**.

FYI (Summary taken from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/1020/thread-sleep-java))

Java Thread Sleep important points

- It always pause the current thread execution.
- Thread sleep doesn’t lose any monitors or locks current thread has
  acquired.
- Any other thread can interrupt the current thread in sleep, in that
  case InterruptedException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

move the System.out statement to finally block.

Answer (score 0):

waiting for some(like 10) seconds your compiler to use this static class method

**TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);**

 it's including in 
**java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit** libery